# Django request.user resets to AnonymousUser after redirect via url

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I have a Django project that is used a basic authentication (django.contrib.auth). I am using a middleware to check if an user is authenticated to redirect to a login page if not. It works as expected until I am using site urls like the following

```
path("edit/<int:id>/", netinventory_views.NodeEdit, name="edit"),
path("nodes/<int:id>/", netinventory_views.NodeTest, name="test"),
```

That cause request.user is reset to AnonymousUser.

middleware.py:

```
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.cache import cache

EXEMPT_URLS = [settings.LOGIN_URL.lstrip('/')]

if hasattr(settings, 'LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS'):
    EXEMPT_URLS += [url for url in settings.LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS]

class AuthRequiredMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_request(self, request):
          path = request.path_info.lstrip('/')
          if request.user.is_authenticated:
              user = request.user
              cache.set('_cached_user', user)
              return
          else:
             if path not in EXEMPT_URLS:
                 return redirect('login')
```

Comment: There is a builtin mixing doing exactly that.https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin

Comment: That doesn't work as a user is set to AnonymousUser and mixing redirects to login page again. I suspect that the issue is with a new id passing during the url execution.